# There are deep learning methods for string similarity in machine translation?

Tags: matlab, string-comparison, feature-extraction, machine-translation

I am interested in machine translation and more specific I would like to examine the similarity between two strings. I would like to know if there are deep learning methods for text feature extraction. I already tried the famous statistics methods like cosine similarity, Levenstein distance, word frequency and others.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the similarity between 2 string ,try to train a **Siamese networks**
on your dataset

**Siamese networks** are a special type of neural network architecture. Instead of a model learning to classify its inputs, the neural networks learns to differentiate between two inputs. It learns the similarity between them.

https://medium.com/@gautam.karmakar/manhattan-lstm-model-for-text-similarity-2351f80d72f1

The below is the link of a kaggle competition ,they have used siamese networks for text simmilarity

https://medium.com/mlreview/implementing-malstm-on-kaggles-quora-question-pairs-competition-8b31b0b16a07

Hope this clears your doubts